# Inserting time into database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, sql-insert

The below piece of code isn't working the way it is supposed to

```
$t = date('Y-d-m H:i:s',time());
$query = "INSERT INTO time VALUES('$t')";
if(mysql_query($query))
echo "Date and Time are added";
```

I have created a table named `time` with only one column `now` and `DATETIME` as *datatype*. Even though the **PHP** script executes successfully in the browser by printing `"Date and Time are added"`. 

The database isn't updating the way it is supposed to be. Rather than the *current time*, it gets initialized to default value. 

Do suggest the way to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NOW()

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `time` (`now`) VALUES (NOW())";
```

Comment: Renamed the table as test and the query works good. Thank you. And when you say the 'Whole code' apart from code for connecting to database there is none to post.

can you do suggest the errors in the above code(ie using a variable)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Now the code works good. Naming the table as time might have been the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of $t from

```
$t = date('Y-d-m H:i:s',time());
```

to

```
$t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Even better method would be to write your insert query like this:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO `time` VALUES ('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this format

```
$t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "INSERT INTO time (now) VALUES('$t')";
if(mysql_query($query))
echo "Date and Time are added";
```

OR

```
$query = "INSERT INTO time (now) VALUES(NOW())";
```

Comment: Even After editing to YY-mm-dd it works the same way.

Comment: The piece of code with now() works good, yet the one with variable doesn't.

Comment: Have renamed the table and now the code works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/* YOU NEED TO ESTABLISH FIRST A CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$t = date('Y-d-m H:i:s');
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO time (now) VALUES ('$t')");
echo "Date and Time are added";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't post the connection code for security purpose. And after renaming the table the code works good.

Comment: please click the tick as the solution for you.

Comment: @Darthstroke did my answer solved your problem? If it does, just tick that check on the side of my answer to mark my answer accepted. :)