# Why its not displaying current time zone?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add parameter in query which passes indian time zone to mysql database server.But when i am passing this query it shows **`0000-00-00 00:00:00`** in my table.
I am using hostinger php my admin database server.
Please help me to solve this.

```
<?php


include 'confi.php';

 date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Maldives');

    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']) : "";
    $today = date("d/m/Y h:i:s A");

    $sql ="INSERT INTO `i_order` (`ID`, `email`,`date`) VALUES (NULL, '$email', '$today');"; 

    $qur = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($qur){
        $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "success!");
    }else{
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "error!");
    }

@mysqli_close($conn);

/* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006692/get-current-date-given-a-timezone-in-php

Comment: this may be caused by $today = date("d/m/Y h:i:s A");, which is a stirng not a timestamp

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Maldives')
 $today = date(m-d-Y);

Comment: https://eval.in/794650

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22703765/6521116

Comment: i tried that but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mysql insert date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

To store a date to MySQL it needs to be in a specific format i.e.

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

So if you change your format from

```
$today = date("d/m/Y h:i:s A");
```

To

```
$today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

The date will store correctly.

The AM and PM part is irrelevant if you are storing a 24 hrs time to thedatabase, you might add that if you were presenting the time to a user, when you read the data back from the database though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869874/how-store-date-in-mysql-database Read THis First okk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format .... See This

Comment: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962736/why-its-not-displaying-current-time-zone/43962844#comment74956257_43962843) and then read up on STR_TO_DATE

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

 date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Maldives');
 //echo $today = date('m-d-Y h:i:s A');

?>
```

Comment: who said  ?? can you explain me why ??

Comment: The simple solution to that question would be to try it and see!

Comment: Just to clarify, I am saying that a date in that format will not store to a MYSQL table column. I am not saying that the `date()` will not work

Comment: You probably need to review what [STR_TO_DATE() actually does](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) It takes a date formatteed in a way THAT IS NOT LEGAL and makes a LEGAL date format for DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP out of a badly formatted date

Comment: Or read the section in YELLOW at the top of [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12120457/2310830)

Comment: @RiggsFolly what about poin no 3

Comment: Yup. So if you actually read ALL of that point 3 it will agree with me

Comment: Anyway, no need to argue. Try to store a date in `m-d-Y` format to a MySQL DATE or DATETIME column and tell me you dont get a `0000-00-00 00:00:00` result !!!